# How to manually create Pageable object from a string

Tags: java, spring

I didn't find anywhere whether it's possible to create pageable manually from string, let assume that we have the following service method

```
public <T> List<T> findAnything(final int page, final int size, final String sort) { // e.g. id,desc&username,asc

    final Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(page, size, null);
    return null;
}
```

my question is how can i instantiate an object of

> org.springframework.data.domain.Sort

from a given string of format, important note that these parameters are chagned dynamically, so more likely i need a path to the spring parser, in my example im passing null instead the object

> id,desc&username,asc

**EDIT**

A little bit more details I'm looking for a mechanism of how spring converts the 'sort' string(with the rest of default parameters) that's coming to the rest endpoint as a query param to Pageable object

Comment: what does the given format mean? `id,desc,username,asc` Did you probably mean `sort=id,desc&sort=username,asc`? It's how Spring recognises a `Sort` object

Comment: thanks in my case these params come as id,desc&username,asc string, updated the format, sorry for confusions

Comment: Hi @hdmiimdh I tried out your code and it threw me an error "The constructor is not visible" (in reference to the 'new PageRequest()' constructor in your code).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do :

```
private Sort orderBy() {
    return new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "ID")
                .and(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "username"));
}
```

I think this is helpful

Sort class has static nested class Order :

```
public static class Order{
    private final Direction direction;
    private final String property;
    private final boolean ignoreCase;
    private final NullHandling nullHandling;
}
```

and then you can use :

```
public static Sort by(List<Order> orders)
```

where you create your Order from String like simply splitting.

Comment: this parameters are changed dynamically as you can see from the method signature, so that's actually not what im looking for

Comment: This answer actually gives you everything you need. You sure do know how to pass a `String` parameter to a method. Well then, pass it into the `orderBy` method.

Comment: seems like you do not quite understand the problem

Comment: You can convert your String to Map and then populate from map Sort elements 
Map<String,Sort.Direction> where id would be the column name and value order

Comment: good now you understood the problem, might be there is a default method that spring uses to do the same thing, for sure i can write it manually, but i can't believe that it's never been exposed

Comment: if you mean the solution above, i don't think that i was asking of how to pass parameters to the constructor :)

Comment: @MykhailoMoskura Now, it makes much more sense. Considering that the format `id,desc,username,asc` isn't regular, building a `List<Order>` is a good option. Actually, that's what `SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` does. Upvoted.

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko ,Thanks

Comment: thanks guys, SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver actually does the thing, but its method parseParameterIntoSort to parse the arguments has package-private access for some hidden reasons, accepted thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2):

For that purpose I've written something similar to what spring has, i'd be happy if spring exposes SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.parseParameterIntoSort for usage outside the package but so far it's not

```
private Sort parseMultipleSortQueries(final String query) {

    final String[] queries = query.split("&");
    return parseSortQuery(queries, ",");
}

private Sort parseSortQuery(final String[] query, String delimiter) {

    final List<Sort.Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String q : query) {

        if (q == null) {
            continue;
        }

        final String[] parts = q.split(delimiter);
        final Sort.Direction direction = parts.length == 0 ? null : Sort.Direction.fromStringOrNull(parts[parts.length - 1]);
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {

            if (i == parts.length - 1 && direction != null) {
                continue;
            }

            final String property = parts[i];
            if (!StringUtils.hasText(property)) {
                continue;
            }
            orders.add(new Sort.Order(direction, property));
        }
    }
    return orders.isEmpty() ? null : new Sort(orders);
}
```

and here is the test

```
@Test
public void testParseQuery() {
    System.out.println(parseMultipleSortQueries("firstName,asc&lastName,desc")); //firstName: ASC,lastName: DESC
}
```